# Restricting PHP directory access in IIS7

Tags: php, windows, iis-7

I searched SO, but only found this for Apache.

In IIS7 for `ONE` specific website, how do I restrict PHP 5.3.8 (FASTCGI) so it can only access files within that website's directory.

For example using include (or anything that lists files/directories) won't be able access anything but current and children directories, no parents.

**What I have tried:**
In IIS7 after clicking the website in the left panel, then in the right panel clicking PHP Manager, I added `open_basedir` directive with the path. This worked, with a caveat, it forced this directive on ALL the websites, which broke all of the other PHP websites on the server.

thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone in IIS7 has this issue, I was able to solve this by opening the php.ini and adding below:

```
[PATH=C:/inetpub/website1.com/www/]
open_basedir=/www/
```